# Can we deploy the independent /separate web application on same server‘s IIS on which SharePoint applications are installed?

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a Windows server 2008 with  IIS on which SharePoint applications are installed.

Can we deploy the independent /separate web application on same server‘s  IIS on which SharePoint applications are installed ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, though they'll need different virtual hosts (so that they're accessed through different URLs).

They can use the same IP address and port if you want, although they don't have to. If you're running multiple HTTPS sites, then each site will need its own certificate and will thus need its own IP address, but that's still possible with one server, just a bit more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as Thriggle suggested but make sure that you don't share the app pool of any SP web app with another web app, both for security and maintainability purposes.